# text wrap using angular library

Tags: javascript, angular

```js
  
    const fileName = 'Process_History_export.xlsx';
        const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(exportData);
        const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();

        XLSX.writeFile(wb, fileName);
```

What's the logic to wrap text for excel cell for above code ?

Comment: Hello, welcome on SO. How do you end up with `angular` tag for your question ? And I would advise you add a liitle more context to your question, it's very hard to understand your point. Cheers :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.